# Inline check for integer while reading a file

Tags: java, validation

This is in java. The inFile is a Scanner.
I have to read from a text file and store the information in an array. The text file contains both integers and strings. I have created a string array to store all the data.

The data is information about cities as follows:

```
1 LV Las Vegas 500000 300

2 B Bakersfield 150000 400
```

I need to store the city name as one field in the array even if it is two words. Is there an inline way to check if the next item in the text file is an integer? I want to store in the array if it is an integer, and concatenate with the previous field if it is a string.

This is what I have. I tried to us isDigit, as in my code below, but it didn't work.

```
private static Scanner inFile;
inFile = new Scanner(new File("city.dat"));

while (inFile.hasNext()){
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++){
            for (int j = 0; j<5; j++){
                if (i == 3){
                    String temp = inFile.next();

                    // if (temp.isDigit){

                     }
                }
                cities[i][j]=inFile.next();
            }
        }
    }
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What language is this? What type is inFile?

Comment: Sorry. Its Java. The inFile is a Scanner. I have edited the OP to reflect this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `inFile` is a `Scanner` object; You can try this:

```
while (inFile.hasNext()){
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++){
            for (int j = 0; j<5; j++){
                if (j == 2) {
                     StringBuilder temp = new StringBuilder(inFile.next());

                     while(!inFile.hasNextInt()){
                         temp.append(" " + inFile.next());
                     }
                     cities[i][j]=temp.toString();
                     continue;
                }
                cities[i][j]=inFile.next();
            }
        }
    }
```

Note the `if ( j == 2 )`; I'm guessing you want to do this check for the third field of the entry?